# Translation of a scientific title

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, neo-latin

I need to translate the following title of a scientific paper into Latin – indeed, Neo-Latin, with neologisms, but keeping classical grammar as much as possible.
It is: 'On the influence of dark matter on stellar formation and evolution.'
I am struggling with finding a classical word for 'influence'.

Comment: Did you find good classical words for the rest? Please share your working title and the reasoning behind it. It will be of great help to anyone who might answer.

Answer (score 3):

For "influence" I would suggest *effectus, us*, which can be combined with *in* + acc. to say "effect on something." (Don't go looking for this in the dictionaries; but peruse a Google search like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=de+effectu+in+corpus&tbm=bks) for many examples.)

So you end up with something like:

> De effectu materiae obscurae in genesim (?) stellarum, etc.

Honestly I find "formation" and "evolution" trickier to find classical equivalents for (certainly not *evolutio*, for example). De quibus quidem non rogasti.